# Does /usr/bin/mail have a queue?

Tags: rhel, email, mail-command

RHEL 5

I'm using a perl service monitoring script (written by a colleague that is no longer with the company) running on an old RHEL 5 box.  If a service is down, it sends an email alert to the root user:

```
            # Email administrator
            if ($retval == 0 && $config{'MAX_EMAILS'} > 0) {
                $service_restarts{$service} = 0;
                system("echo \"This notification was generated because $service was down and has been successfully restarted.\"
 | /bin/mail -s \"Monitor: $service restarted ($date)\" root");
            }
```

In `/etc/aliases` I have:

```
root:            fooadmin@fooexample.blah
```

My question is -- what services need to be running in order for mail sent to root to get relayed to the external alias?  If those services are down, will `/usr/bin/mail` queue?

Answer (score 3):

`mail` is pretty dumb and usually just lobs the message off to a `sendmail` binary. Unfortunately there are multiple implementations of `mail` so you'd ideally need to inspect the docs or code to see what sort of error handling (if any) is done for the exact version in use.

In addition to the mail service that `sendmail` is part of—Mail Transport Agents (MTA) which on RHEL5 would most likely be Sendmail or Postfix—you will likely also need DNS as the MTA will need to perform a DNS lookup on `fooexample.blah` to be able to send there. Possibly also a MTA queue runner if there's a temporary failure and the email ends up in a MTA queue directory somewhere (RHEL MTA include such queue runners by default). Oh, and a filesystem, if `/var` or whatever is full the MTA will probably not be able to queue additional mails and therefore will likely not accept the message from `mail`. (Especially if due to some other error the alert system fills up `/var` and then more alerts are created and then when it unbreaks you have to call the pager company because they disabled your pager because it got sent a bazillion alerts and oh I so do not miss those days.)

... and a working network, depending on how broadly you want to define service ... and also there are optional but commonly used anti-spam services; what happens when Gmail or Exchange are rejecting or discarding your alerts as spam?

Also do note the lack of error checking on that `system` call; `mail` (or a `fork` or `exec` call) could fail, and then what? Slightly more sensible may be to log such failures somewhere:

```
use Sys::Syslog;
openlog("homegrown-monitoring-101", "ndelay", "user");

system("echo ... root") == 0
  or syslog(LOG_ERR, "non-zero exit code from mail command");
```

And then ideally have [something like `sec.pl`](https://simple-evcorr.github.io) check for `homegrown-monitoring-101` logs and report on them (via a grouped summary, not the usual cron spam of one email per log message...).

`mail` or the MTA may also leave `dead.letter` files somewhere (assuming it can write to where it wants to write those) which monitoring in theory could check for, but if there's a new `dead.letter` and your alerting is via email, you probably need some other protocol to report that error.

On centos 7 systems I instead use the `perl-Email-Sender` package over `mail` to lob messages places:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.16.0;
use warnings;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Simple;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

...

my $message = ...;
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        To      => $username . '@example.edu',
        From    => 'nobody@example.edu',
        Subject => "...",
    ],
    body => $message,
);
sendmail($email);
```